# I cannot npm install with just created vue2 + vuetify proj

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs2, vue-cli

installed latest vue/cli and created project using vue2.
After this, I added vuetify and thats all for additional to basic vue2 template list of packages.

When I have tryed to use 'npm install'

```
Found: @vue/cli-service@undefined
npm ERR! node_modules/@vue/cli-service
npm ERR!   dev @vue/cli-service@"5.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @vue/cli-service@"^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0-0" from @vue/cli-plugin-babel@5.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-babel
npm ERR!   dev @vue/cli-plugin-babel@"5.0.0" from the root project`
```

can you guys explain me meaning of error
[myVersions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDYnK.png)

Answer (score 1):

As you are seemingly on an old version of `npm` (<=6.x) you need to install the peer dependency yourself:

```
npm i -D @vue/cli-service@5.0.0
```

After installing the dependency, edit your `package.json` and insert this block on the top level, right after the `"devDependencies"` object:

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.0"
}
```

and remove that dependency from the `"devDependencies"` object.

If you don't want to deal with peer dependencies yourself, upgrade your node and npm version. To upgrade `npm` only:

```
npm i -g npm
```

Comment: problem is still there, got same error when try to npm i -D @vue/cli-service@5.0.0
you can see my versions on image i`v added

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that I reconfigured entire project. I will anyway answer this question.

Issue was related to cli-service 5.0.0, when I should have had 5.0.8 in order to use babel 5.0.0.

I want to add that if you use default vue.2 template with vue/cli 5.0.8,
You will get another error after installing vuetify, which was not able to fix.

Error is related to vuetify loader.
I fixed it with start up new project and manually inserting all dependencies compatible with vuetify-loader 1.5
Because 1.7 brakes npm run serve